# Find $n$ if the coefficient of $x^3$ and $x^4$ in the expansion of $(2+x)^n$ are in the ratio $4:11$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Find  $n$ if the coefficient of $x^3$ and $x^4$ in the expansion of $(2+x)^n$ are in the ratio $4:11$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You consider the ratio:
$$\frac{\frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!}\cdot 2^{n-3}}{\frac{n!}{4!(n-4)!}\cdot 2^{n-4}}=\frac{4\cdot 2}{n-3}=\frac{4}{11} \Rightarrow n=25.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- The expression $(2+x)^n$ can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \binom{n}{k} x^k2^{n-k}$$ using the binomial theorem.
- Can you then find the coefficients of $x^3$ and $x^4$?

Comment: The coefficient are given in a ratio 4:11

Comment: What I need to find now is the value of "ń"

Comment: Please I need steps to get "n"